# Need Help On using APIs of open sources

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I have started working on various open source frameworks like zookeeper, Hadoop, Solr. I have learnt their architecture . But when it comes to develop applications using JAVA API , where will i get the packages containing API that will be compatible with the version of framework . Is it like when i download the framework(Zookeeper) , the jar files (needed for API) also comes along with it. I am a  beginner with java , and it might seem a silly question to all of you. Please help me out by sharing your knowledge.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The depends on what tools you use. First, understand that if you "download the framework" as you state what you are doing is downloading the "jar files (needed for the API)". That is the only thing to be downloaded. In some cases there might be a `core` jar and an `api` jar but this is what constitutes the "framework" and what must be downloaded and added to your applications classpath.

That said, if you use a tool like Maven, it will take care of a lot of this for you once you add the framework as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks John. So i down loaded the Zookeeper frame work and i found the API jar in that , and i could run my first program using the API too.I don have any idea regarding Maven, is it like make file as i have used in c ,c++. Is there any reference to learn about Maven.

Comment: Google it, there is tons of documentation online. At it's simplest it is the Java version of make files.